# Determine $p$ for one to have $\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1+1}{5+6}=\frac{2}{11}$, in $\mathbb{Z_p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine $p$ for one to have $\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1+1}{5+6}=\frac{2}{11}$, in $\mathbb{Z_p}$.

I know that $p$ must, $13, 43, 61, 101,103$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try multiplying both sides by $11 \cdot 5 \cdot 6$, to get $$121 = 11 \cdot 6 + 11 \cdot 5 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 = 60$$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: At this opportunity, I idly wonder why we so often write "Try" this, instead of "Do".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to $p=121-60=61$ we can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to obtain $5^{-1}=-12$, $6^{-1}=-10$ and $11^{-1}=-11$ in $\mathbb{Z}/61 \mathbb{Z}$. Hence
$$
\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}=-12-10=-22=2\cdot (-11)=\frac{2}{11}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure what has to be done here, as mentioned above: we will multiply in the following way:

$$(11 \cdot 5 \cdot 6)\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)=\left((11 \cdot 5 \cdot 6)\frac{2}{11}\right)$$, in $\mathbb{Z_p}$

then we get $11\cdot6 + 11\cdot 5= 121 = 5 \cdot 6\cdot 2 = 60$, but this is only possible inside the $\mathbb{Z_{61}}$, observe that in this ring (because $p$ is prime), we have that $61 = 0 \in \mathbb{Z_{61}} $ and that $122 = 0$, so $121 = 60$.